# A number sequence: 3, 26, 83,

Tags: number-sequence

Genius level!

3, 26, 83, 1196, 2915, ?

Comment: Just as a friendly heads-up, generally putting your own difficulty rating doesn't go down particularly well on Puzzling... (see this [meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1437/can-we-please-edit-very-hard-difficult-and-easy-out-of-titles?)) Let the puzzler try it and decide for themselves! :) (PS Didn't downvote you!)

Comment: Haha ok. Now I know :)

Comment: I've edited the fluff out of the title now :-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 5244 (add concetanation of two subsequent primes 23,57,1113,1719,2329)

Comment: Is this incorrect?